# Changing values situation?

Tags: replace, exchange-server, notepad++

How do I change or replace, in notepad2 or anywhere, _a for _b and viceversa without changing _a for _b first and now having everything as _b??

Comment: Did you forget to place your code in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

1. Replace _a for _XXXX
2. Replace _b for _a
3. Replace _XXXX for _a

It's the same as within a script, if you want to change values, you have to make a temp to hold the old value of the first param. Here we do the same, we make a _XXXX which will be replaced after to the other var.